# Linear programming: can someone explain how the time steps work here?

Tags: functions, linear-programming

I'm reading a paper, "[A Player Selection Heuristic for a Sports League Draft](http://people.emich.edu/aross15/math319/player-selection-heuristic-sports-league-draft.pdf)". In it, the authors have come up with a method to assist you in picking players for a fantasy sports league. I'm having some trouble understanding how to read the formula that's created. Below I've included the formulas and variables I understand.

$\vec{i^k_t}$ player *k*'s needs vector at time *t*. *k* is always 0 in this paper; it represents the user of the algorithm.

$g(\vec{i^0_t}, a)$ a function that returns player 0's new needs vector when (s)he selects player *a* in the state $\vec{i^0_t}$

$r(a, \vec{i^0_t})$ the value added to user 0's team when player *a* is added to the needs vector.

$\Omega_t$ plausible players to select at time *t*

Here is an equation for computing the maximum value team 0 can draft from round *t* through the end of the draft. This isn't explicitly said for this equation, but is mentioned earlier (equation 1 in the paper), but I assume the same thing is being accomplished.
$$
v_t(\vec{i^0_t}) = \operatorname{max}a\in\Omega_t \{r(a, \vec{i^0_t}) + v_{t+1}(g(\vec{i^0_t}, a)) \}
$$

Given this information, I don't understand how $v_t$ applies to the linear programming solution, which is as follows:

min $v_1(\vec{i^0_1})$

s.t. $v_t(\vec{i^0_t}) \ge r(a, \vec{i^0_t}) + v_{t+1}(g(\vec{i^0_t}, a)) \quad \forall_t, \vec{i^0_t}, a\in\Omega_t$

Is the first equation for $v_t$ at all related? Reading the paper, I gathered the linear programming solution was a translation of it. Looking at the equation, I don't understand why/how $v_t$ is being computed by then using $v_{t+1}$.

I've looked at the Wikipedia page on linear programming, but the example shown is with matrices, which is how I've done it in the past.

Comment: I asked around in real life and this is what I think is happening. The paper assumes you: 1) know everyone's draft strategy; 2) everyone is using the same strategy. So it initializes on your first pick, and gives you all the optimal picks. It's just brute force.